# Select n-th lowest value from DataFrame (Every Row!)

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am looking for a solution to pick values (row wise) from a Dataframe.
Here is what I already have:

```
np.random.seed(1)
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(1,10, (10, 10)))
df.columns = list('ABCDEFGHIJ')

N = 2
idx = np.argsort(df.values, 1)[:, 0:N]

df= pd.concat([pd.DataFrame(df.values.take(idx), index=df.index), pd.DataFrame(df.columns[idx], index=df.index)],keys=['Value', 'Columns']).sort_index(level=1)
```

Now I have the index/position for every value but if I try to get the values from the Dataframe it only takes the values from the first row.
What do I have to change in the code?

df looks like:

```
   A  B  C  D  E  F  G  H  I  J
0  6  9  6  1  1  2  8  7  3  5
1  6  3  5  3  5  8  8  2  8  1
2  7  8  7  2  1  2  9  9  4  9
....
```

My output should look like:

```
0  D E
0  1 1
1  J H
1  1 2
```

Comment: What's the expected output?

Comment: The expected output should give me for every row the n-th lowest values.

Comment: Can you post the expected output to the question? You can [edit] from here

Comment: Why not sort directly? `np.sort(df.to_numpy(), axis=1)[:, :N]`

Comment: @HenryYik Sorting directly then we loose which column name to take corresponding to n smallest value in each row.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`np.take_along_axis`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.take_along_axis.html) to take values from dataframe. Use [`np.insert`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.insert.html) to sieve both values taken and corresponding column names.

```
# idx is the same as the one used in the question.

vals = np.take_along_axis(df.values, idx, axis=1)
cols = df.columns.values[idx]
indices = np.r_[: len(vals)] # same as np.arange(len(vals))

out = np.insert(vals.astype(str), indices , cols, axis=0)
index = np.repeat(indices, 2)
df = pd.DataFrame(out, index=index)

   0  1
0  D  E
0  1  1
1  J  H
1  1  2
2  E  D
2  1  2
3  E  I
3  2  2
4  A  D
4  1  1
5  I  J
5  1  3
6  E  I
6  1  2
7  B  H
7  1  3
8  G  I
8  1  1
9  E  A
9  1  2
```

Comment: Thank you it works perfectly! But how can I take the index from the original df? So in case the index of df are different values instead of 0 to x

Comment: @Wayne2 Thank you. Nice question too.

Comment: If it solved your question, consider accepting this as the answer by clicking tick next to answer and upvote. ;) @Wayne2